# webpackdevserver listen callback not being called

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have webpack dev server that's always been working and now suddenly it's not. The issue is that the callback for `WebpackDevServer.listen` never gets called. Nothing crashes and no error is being sent the callback just never gets called. Does anyone know why this would happen? Is there some setup where the callback will be ignored?

```
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(STATIC_PORT, HOST, err => {
      console.log('this never gets called');
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my computer did the trick.. So that's my answer so far. If this happens to you, try restarting pc.

If anyone else has a better explanation of why this happens and if there's a way to avoid it in the future I will mark your answer as correct.